# CSS aligning form inputs and inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I would like to align my icon elements with the form inputs. This is what I have so far:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3u9qfa3/)

```
<div class="ctr">
    <div class="icon-ctr">
        <span class="icon"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.ctr {
    font-size: 0;
}

.ctr input {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.icon-ctr {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: -1px;
}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

You'll notice that the elements don't align in a straight line as I had hoped. Firstly what property is causing this? And secondly what is the most appropriate way to align the elements in a straight line?

Comment: I would wrap the input in a div that has the same height as the icon div. that way you can properly align the contents of both. Also, don't use padding to center things, use vertical-align. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: I know that if you use `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block` that they do line up correctly. Interesting that inline-block isn't working I'm going to check into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline block elements, by default, align to the baseline of the previous element.

All you need to do is vertically align the input to the top of the icon.

```
.ctr input
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3u9qfa3/15/)

Comment: Whilst the other answers were good and answered how to solve the problem, this answer gave reason for the issue I was describing. Works a treat, and explains why floating the elements works too as floated elements are taken out of the normal flow and are then not positioned relative to the preceding element's baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Use in `.icon-ctr` add `float: left;`

```css
.ctr {
  font-size: 0;
}
.ctr input {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.icon-ctr {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctr">
  <div class="icon-ctr">
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```